# Missing number issue in table - first with no issue

Tags: tables, missing

I wrote my CV using Overleaf.
Using multiple times the tabular function, I have no issues.
In the references, I get two errors by Overleaf:

- Missing number, treated as zero.
- Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).

Interestingly, the first reference gets no error note; it appears only in Fnu Snu 2 and Fnu Snu 3 at the code line of the Email.
The output pdf is as envisioned, however I would like to have a proper code.
Can anyone help me and especially explain why the errors only occur in Fnu Snu 2 and Fnu Snu 3 but not in Fnu Snu 1?

```
% Format
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\scshape}{}{0pt}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{10pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}{3pt plus 0pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\cvdescript}[4]
    {\begin{itemize}[align=left,labelwidth=100pt,labelsep=8.5pt,leftmargin=!]
        \item [{#1}]{{\textbf{#2}}\\{\textsl{#3}}\\{#4}}
    \end{itemize}}

%Content
\begin{document}
%all working fine until following section
\section{References}
    \cvdescript{}{Fnu Snu 1}
    {Information 1}
    {\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.12\textwidth} l}
        E-Mail: & \href{mailto:fnu.snu1@provider.com}{fnu.snu1@provider.com}\end{tabular}}
    \skip
    \cvdescript{}{Fnu Snu 2}
    {Information 2}
    {\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.12\textwidth} l}
        E-Mail: & \href{mailto:fnu.snu2@provider.com}{fnu.snu2@provider.com}\end{tabular}}
    \skip
    \cvdescript{}{Fnu Snu 3}
    {PInformation 3}
    {\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.12\textwidth} l}
        E-Mail: & \href{mailto:fnu.snu3@provider.com}{fnu.snu3@provider.com}\end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: that solved the issue - thank you very much! @campa

Comment: The comment has been turned into an answer, you can accept it if you like :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\skip` is a TeX primitive to access a skip register (analogous to `\box`, `\dimen`, `\count`, ...); as such it expects a number, which explains the error you observe.

If you want to leave some vertical space you should use one of the macros designed for this purpose, like `\smallskip`, `\medskip`, or `\bigskip`.